# How do I make Apache deliver an Office 2007 file with the correct Content-Type?

Tags: apache-2.2

I am using SVN Server 1.8 and Apache2.2. When I add an Exel 2007 file to a repository, SVN automatically adds svn:mime-type property to "application/octet-stream" to the file. When a client use Internet Explore (IE) 8 to access the file, Apache delivers it as "application/octet-stream" and IE 8 sees it as a .zip file.

I tried to modify httpd.conf to add the type to it as follow:
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet           xlsx

But Apache still delivers the file as "application/octet-stream".

Is there any thing else that I need to set so that Apache can deliver the file with the correct Content-type of "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have this and other vnd.openxmlformats correctly inserted in  **/etc/mime.types**

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation   pptx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide          sldx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow      ppsx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template       potx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet           xlsx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet           xlsx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template        xltx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template        xltx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document     docx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template     dotx
```

Remember to restart Apache after any modifications to mime.types.

**Subversion** itself examines the file in order to determine if it is a binary file with it's own (and rather clumsy) heuristic based on zeros and non-ASCII characters in the first 1024 bytes of the file.

You can tell Subversion to find mime type mappings from a file with runtime configuration parameter `mime-types-file`. On Windows machines the runtime configuration file might be found under %APPDATA%\Subversion. On some installation settings might be in Windows registry, search for something like:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Config\miscellany]
"#mime-types-file"=""
```

Comment: Yes, i have them in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\mime.types (I am running Windows Server 2008) and I restarted Apache every time I modify it.

Comment: When an excel file is added to a repository, SVN automatically attachs svn:mime-type property to it with a value of "application/octet-stream". If I manually remove this property then Apache delivers the file with the correct Content-type as specified in .../mime.types.

Comment: It appears that Apaches will takes the MIME type specified in SVN property first, if that does not exist then it look for it in .../mime.types. Is there a way to change that? If that is not possible, can we prevent SVN from automatically adding svn:mime-type property to an excel file when it is added to a repository?

Comment: I just updated my answer accordingly. See whether it helps.